# Search Flickr Api by Camera Model

Tags: flickr

Anyone knows if it is possible to use the flickr api to search by a specific camera model?
The camera model is stored in the exif data, but I cpuld find a way to search after exif data.

Comment: Following up nine years later... amazingly, though they have endpoints for listing all known camera brands and their models, and though their website allows for finding photos by camera brand, it's completely undocumented how to do it. I've been hunting for hours and coming up with nothing. Must be possible, but how?

Answer (score 1):

Flickr attaches Tags based on EXIF info in images. One of such tags can help you search based on camera.

Flickr's serach service (http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.search.html) has an option of search by tags.

This is an example of such searches: www.flickr.com/cameras/